# Understanding 0-dim. case in proposition 15.3 in "Introduction to smooth manifolds" by Lee

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, orientation

I am trying to understand the proof of the following proposition. It is taken from Lee's book "Introduction to smooth manifolds":
[image]

I have trouble understanding the 0-dim. case. In partucluar why $\omega>0$ implies $\mathcal{O}_{\omega}$ is +1 and the other case as well.

Since it says this case is immediate I suppose I am missing something obvious, but unfortunately I am completely stuck. I am also not sure what "consistently oriented" means in the case of a 0-dim. vector space. There is only a definition for the case $n\geq 1$. In Jänich's book "Vector Analysis" I found something that would make sense to me regarding the definion of orientaion in the 0-dim. case. It is the following:

[image]
[image]

Then $\mathcal{O}_{\omega}=[\emptyset]$, since the empty set is the only ordered basis in $V=0$?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that my book gives a separate definition of orientations of zero-dimensional vector spaces, which doesn't have anything to do with consistently oriented bases. The definition appears on page 379, about a third of the way down the page:

> For the special case of a zero-dimensional vector space $V$, we define
> an orientation of $V$ to be simply a choice of one of the numbers $\pm 1$.

In the statement of Proposition 15.3, the sentence "if $n=0$, then $\mathscr O_\omega$ is $+1$ if $\omega>0$, and $-1$ if $\omega<0$" is not a claim to be proved -- it's the ***definition*** of the orientation $\mathscr O_\omega$ determined by a particular choice of $\omega$.

Since $\Lambda^0 V^* = \mathbb R$ (no matter what the dimension of $V$ is), in the case $n=0$, an element $\omega\in \Lambda^n V^*$ is just a real number, and any such number specifies a unique orientation of $V$ by the recipe quoted above.

The only thing to be proved in that case is the claim that two nonzero $0$-covectors (i.e., nonzero real numbers) determine the same orientation if and only if each is a positive multiple of the other, and this is just the statement that two nonzero real numbers have the same sign iff each is a positive multiple of the other.

Comment: Now things are a lot clearer! Thanks! In the book "An introduction to Manifolds" by Tu I found the statement that each connected component of $ \Lambda^{n}(V^{*})$ determines an orientation. Could that be taken as a definition of orientation that includes the 0-dim. case? In my lecture notes this given as the definition of orientation without any further explanation. To me this definition makes little to no sense without showing how it relates to the more "intuitive/geometric" approaches. In other words that the "intuitive/geometric" can be, let's say "characterised", by the...

Comment: ..."connected component approach"? Or am I missing something again?

Comment: You can't use connected components of $\Lambda^n(V^*)$, because it's connected. But you can define an orientation to be a connected component of $\Lambda^n(V^*)\smallsetminus\{0\}$ in all dimensions. The fact that this definition is equivalent to the one I use follows very easily from my Proposition 15.3, once you observe that two elements of $\Lambda^n(V^*)\smallsetminus\{0\}$ are in the same connected component if and only if each is a positive multiple of the other.

Comment: Oh...I meant  $\Lambda^{n}(V^{*})\setminus\{0\}$ of course. Okay. Could the last statement be proved like this:  I would first show that $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$ and $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}_{<0})$ are the components. Now consider $\beta ,\beta^{'}$ and suppose they are in the same component and let $\phi$ denote the isomorphism, then $\phi(\beta),\phi(\beta^{'})$ are either both positive or negative.

Comment: Hence, they are positive multiples For the other direction: Suppose $\beta\in\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$, $\beta^{'}\in\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}_{<0})$,i.e. not in the same component and $\beta=a\cdot\beta^{'}$ Then $0<\phi(\beta)=\phi(a\cdot\beta^{'})=a\cdot\phi(\beta^{'})<0$, which is not possible.

Comment: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 2):

The exterior algebra of an $n$-dimensional vector space is $2^n$ dimensional. In particular, the exterior algebra for a $0$-dimensional vector space is $2^0 = 1$ dimensional, and coincides with the space of real numbers. Since the elements of the exterior algebra are just real numbers, the sign of the number determines the orientation. The $0$-dimensional case is most a matter of convention. As Jänich points out, taking a second orientation in the $0$-dimensional case turns out to be useful sometimes.